# How to access to my FTP server outside and inside home?

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I couldn't find out how to access my ftp server. I searched a lot on Google but I have not found anything useful.

I configured my ftp server in Filezilla and eveything works fine but I can only access it from the desktop that hosts the service by typing `ftp://iplocal:port`

If I try to connect from another device in the local area by typing the local IP of it nothing happens. Also I can't access it with the external IP of my house.

Comment: I presume you have a router, you will need to forward the port the FTP Server is running on to local LAN address assigned to the device running the FTP Server.    I suggest you don't allow insecure FTP connections though.

Comment: @Ramhound i don't why i can't find it on my router settings they just show me which port triggered and wich is open and i put 21 for both but i don't have a feild to set the ip adress of the device that hosting the server so what can i do please help!

Comment: If you cannot forward your port, then you cannot do, what you describe.  If your networking hardware does not suport it, get different networking hardware, that does support it.

Comment: @Ramhound i forwarded the port but i can't set the ip of the host, So u think that my router hardware doesn't support it?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot set the ip of the host?  If you cannot do that, then you have not, done port forwarding to your FTP host.

Comment: With regards to being able to access it on your LAN, have you disabled the firewall on the server? You haven't mentioned the OS of your server, could you [edit] your question with that information?

Comment: @Ramhound so you think that i can forwared the port beacause of my router's hardware?